# Rails - Regex help building a method that breaks long words with a <wbr> tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

Helo, I want to pass a block of html/text, could include links, into a method. The method needs to break words with more than 10 characters. Here's what I have so far:

```
def magic_format(str, len = 10)
 fragment = /.{#{len}}/
 str.split(/(\s+)/).map! { |word|
  (/\s/ === word) ? word : word.gsub(fragment, '\0<wbr />')
 }.join


 # AutoLink URLs
 str = auto_link(str, :html => { :target => '_blank' })

end
```

The gsub doesn't seem to be working for some reason, it isn't adding wbr tags.

Thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map and regex part of that works (not sure if it's the nicest way of doing it, but it works). It's just not changing `str`. This should do the trick...

```
def magic_format(str, len = 10)
  fragment = /.{#{len}}/
  str = str.split(/(\s+)/).map! { |word|
    (/\s/ === word) ? word : word.gsub(fragment, '\0<wbr />')
  }.join

  auto_link(str, :html => { :target => '_blank' })
end
```